# Nuxt 3 / github actions failing

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, github-actions, nuxtjs3

Implementing github actions for a nuxt 3 site and it is failing at "nuxi prepare" not sure why this is failing. I used github actions for a Nuxt 2 site and it always ran smoothly. is this an issue with "Nuxi" or should I use "Nuxt"?

workflow file where its failing:

```
  - if: ${{env.USE_CACHE == 'false'}} 
    name: Setup Node (NO-CACHE)
    uses: actions/setup-node@v1
    with:
      node-version: '18'
  - if: ${{env.USE_CACHE == 'false'}}
    name: npm ci (NO-CACHE)
    run: npm ci
```

[image]

Comment: The error says "**nuxi: not found**". Forgot to install it?